# How to get phone screens height and width

Tags: android

I use this code to find the Height and width of the screen

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

But I get `1080 x 1920` for `samsung galaxy S4` and `800 x 1280` for `Nexus 7`. But I actually need the the orginal heigth and width. How to get it.

Comment: It is correct one http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9500_galaxy_s4-5125.php

Comment: but actually Nexus 7 is bigger than samsung galaxy S4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope this may help

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); 
int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
Log.i("MY", "Actual Screen Height = " + screenHeight + " Width = " + screenWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the size without subtracting room for the status bars and other decorations-  use `Display.getRealSize()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
 final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();     
        Method mGetRawH = null,mGetRawW = null;
        int realWidth=0,realHeight=0;

             // For JellyBeans and onward
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){

                display.getRealMetrics(metrics);
                realWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
                realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

            } else{
            // Below Jellybeans you can use reflection method 

            mGetRawH = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
            mGetRawW = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");

            realWidth = (Integer) mGetRawW.invoke(display);
            realHeight = (Integer) mGetRawH.invoke(display);       
       }

    System.out.print(realWidth);
    System.out.print(realHeight);
```

Comment: This logic give me perfect Width and Height as defined in Device Specification.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the pixel values using densityDpi value. This will give dimensions in terms of DP (density independent pixels).

```
    int width =  (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 160)/displayMetrics.densityDpi; 
    int height = (displayMetrics.heightPixels * 160)/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
```